# combine two select queries into one result

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query which has joined different tables and I got this result:

```
product_no       production_title       product_descr    sum(produce_quantity)
 10                bike                   bike              250
 20                mounter bike           moun-bike         300
 30                moto                   moto              400
```

And I have another SQL which selects from one table and returns a result like this:

```
product_ no       Sale_January   Sale_ Feb       ....          Sale_Dec
  10                  10            15                              20
  20                  12            0                               15
```

How can I join the results together? I would like to have a result like this:

```
  product_no  production_title   product_descr   sum(produce_quantity) sale_January .... sale_Dec
     10        bike                   bike              250                   10           20
     20        mounter bike           moun-bike         300                   12           15
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

A simple `join` would seem to work:

```
select *
from result1 r1 join
     result2 r2
     using (product_no);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tb1: product_no       production_title       product_descr    sum(produce_quantity)

tb2: product_ no       Sale_January   Sale_ Freb       ....          Sale_Dec

Select tb1.product_no,  tb1.production_title,  tb1.product_descr,   tb1.sum(produce_quantity), tb2.*

from tb1 inner join tb2 on tb1.product_ no = tb2.product_ no
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this correctly, you have two different queries that are returning the results above. You can use sub-queries to get what you need:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  <SQL for Query1>
) q1 INNER JOIN (
  <SQL for Query2>
) q2 ON q1.product_no = q2.product_no
```